# How to properly recognize the number in this kind of images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to make a script that can identify the number in a picture, more precisely pictures REALLY similar to this one:

[image]

This goes from `50` to `1`, but I'm having some problems reading the number present in there using `pytesseract`. Here's the code I'm using to read it:

```py
im = Image.open(filename)
text = image_to_string(im)
```

All results I get are like this:

[image]

What can I do to improve the readings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) is your "holy scripture" when working with Tesseract. Before binarization, you could first try to [grayscale](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes) your image:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

im = Image.open('G9hvi.png').convert('L')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
print(text.replace('\f', ''))
# 50
```

Boom! – without any further pre-processing you already get the correct result.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.2
Pillow:        8.2.0
pytesseract:   5.0.0-alpha.20201127
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Yeah, some numbers work fine, but then other he can't read. One thing I noticed is, the DPI is nowhere near 300 which is the minimal recommended to use with tesseract so I assume I need to resize the images to have a good dpi but how much do I need to resize?

Comment: Kindly post the images, that don't work. | Read the linked article! Proper image pre-processing is most important. `pytesseract` has no problems properly identifying the numbers in such images. But most likely, the other images have a (maybe only slightly) different appearance, but that can be sufficient for needing a more advanced pre-processing than the presented grayscaling.